# Having trouble making my pricing plan stay together (bootstrap4 formatting issues)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working with bootstrap 4. I am trying to create a pricing plan that stays intact as I move the screen size. I understand @media, but i think this is a position issue. I am not sure how to fix this.

My goal is to have something like this: https://www.chimpcharge.com/pricing

If someone can review my code and let me know where I am going wrong I would really appreciate it.

I put this code in codepen if anyone wants to take a look there: https://codepen.io/rob-connolly/pen/QWNgyNQ

Thank you!

```css
.heroSection {
  background-color: #F8FBFC;
}

.heroText {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #373E42;
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.subHeroText {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(107, 113, 117);
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.priceBox {
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #E9EEF1;
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
}

.dollarSymbol {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.amount {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.mo {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

li.borderless {
  border: 0 none;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.iconFeatures {
  padding-left: 20%;
}

.iconTextPrice {
  padding-left: 5%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding-top: 1%;
  position: relative;
}

.setupText {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#heroButton {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.cancelAnytime {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgb(107, 113, 117);
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:wght@200;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>Clover Networks and TextJet Loyalty</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="./assets/images/TextJet.png" height="28" alt="CoolBrand">
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">How it Works</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Pricing</a>

      </div>
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="http://app.staging.textjet.com/app/login" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="container-flex">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center heroSection heroText">
        <h1>Easy Pricing</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h2 class='text-center subHeroText'>Our everything plan gives you all the tools you need to run a successful loyalty campiagn.</h2>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid heroBottom" src="./assets/images/hero-bottom.png" alt="img for bottom">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-flex pricePageBox">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-5 text-center priceBox">
        <div class="col-12 justify-content-center d-flex justify-content-between;">
          <h2 class="dollarSymbol">$</h2>
          <h2 class="amount">49</h2>
          <h3 class="mo">/mo</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        </div>

        <ul class="list-group ">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between; borderless"><i class="far fa-smile-beam fa-2x iconFeatures" style="color: #F47820;"></i>
            <h5 class="iconTextPrice" style="color: #000;">Unlimited Customers
          </li>


          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between; borderless"><i class="far fa-smile-beam fa-2x iconFeatures" style="color: #F47820;"></i>
              <h5 class="iconTextPrice" style="color: #000;">LoyaltyPlus Tool
            </li>

            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between; borderless"><i class="far fa-smile-beam fa-2x iconFeatures" style="color: #F47820;"></i>
                <h5 class="iconTextPrice" style="color: #000;">RetentionPlus Tool
              </li>

              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between; borderless"><i class="far fa-smile-beam fa-2x iconFeatures" style="color: #F47820;"></i>
                  <h5 class="iconTextPrice" style="color: #000;">Rich Messaging
                </li>

                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between; borderless"><i class="far fa-smile-beam fa-2x iconFeatures" style="color: #F47820;"></i>
                    <h5 class="iconTextPrice" style="color: #000;">2-Way Messaging
                  </li>


                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between; borderless"><i class="far fa-smile-beam fa-2x iconFeatures " style="color: #F47820;"></i>
                      <h5 class="iconTextPrice" style="color: #000;">Clover Integration
                    </li>

                    <ul class="list-group">
                      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between; borderless"><i class="far fa-smile-beam fa-2x iconFeatures" style="color: #F47820;"></i>
                        <h5 class="iconTextPrice" style="color: #000;">Top-Rated Support
                      </li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <h3 class="setupText">Get set-up in 15 minutes. </h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <button id="heroButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign
                                                    Up</button>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12 text-center cancelAnytime">No commitment, Cancel anytime.
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

      </div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have contained the .pricebox container in a .col-5 div. Apply it responsively like .col-md-5 to allow the container to occupy full width on small devices and 5 cols of 12 on larger devices

Answer (score 0):

Move this elements into different `col-auto`s with class: `align-self-center`.

```
  <h2 class="dollarSymbol">$</h2>
  <h2 class="amount">49</h2>
  <h3 class="mo">/mo</h3>
```

Wrap them into a row with `.justify-content-center`

Something like this:

```
[...]
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <h2 class="dollarSymbol">$</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <h2 class="amount">49</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">
        <h3 class="mo">/mo</h3>
    </div>
</div>
[...]
```

I think that should do the trick.